# Transfer file from Windows to Linux without using 3rd party software and using Shell.Application only

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, sftp, windows-server

How to transfer file from Window Server to Linux without using 3rd party software? I just can use pure PowerShell script to transfer zip file.

I'm using **PowerShell v2.0** (I know it's pretty old and I don't have privilege to update to current version - only can use for `Shell.Application` script)

1. Telnet successfully
2. Destination server installed private/public key (which I gen from my server using PuTTYgen - but no privilege to install PuTTY or WinSCP)

```bsh
$timestamp = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$todaysDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$source = "D:\Testing\*.csv", "D:\Testing\*.csv"
$target = "D:\Testing\bin\$timestamp.zip"
$housekeepZipFile = "D:\Testing\bin\*.zip"
$locationToTransfer = "D:\Testing\bin\*.zip"
$mftFileTransfer = "UserName@192.168.0.50:/UserName/Outbox"

Get-ChildItem -Path $locationToTransfer –Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
} | Copy-Item -Destination $mftFileTransfer -Force
```

Is my syntax correct? Just now tried, seems not receive any file.

Using **Window Server 2008**

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use `Shell.Application` at all. Also, it seems you want to transfer the file via SSH/SCP while stuck with a Windows version prior to Windows 8 (which comes with PowerShell v3 preinstalled). None of those versions have a builtin SSH client. Hence you have 2 options: a) use a protocol for which Windows has native support (like SMB or FTP), which requires a corresponding service on the Linux host, or b) put an SSH client on the Windows machine (neither PuTTY nor WinSCP require installation; you can run the standalone executables from wherever you put them).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm using https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/daiken/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget/ this link to compressed file. there is more script above. now is file transferring as prior steps are done.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything I just said?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers how can i enable Window native support (SMB or FTP)? I'm totally new to powershell and file transferring.

Comment: Does your lnux system have .net core installed?

Comment: @ArcSet should be. If there any difference with and without?

Comment: Like I already said, for using SMB or FTP you need to run the corresponding service on the Linux host (Samba for SMB, something like proftpd for FTP). If you have PowerShell Core on the Linux host you may be able to [copy files via WinRM](https://blog.ipswitch.com/use-powershell-copy-item-cmdlet-transfer-files-winrm),

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers copy files via WinRM seems like required both server running powershell v5. My server only on v2.0. hmmm...i was given a pair of "matching" key. only these authenticated "key" only able to transfer file as well.

Comment: As Ansgar already commented, keys are used with SSH/SFTP. There's no support for SSH/SFTP in PowerShell nor in Windows 2008. If you need to use SSH/SFTP, you have to use 3rd party software/library. And as already said above, you do not need *install privileges* to use WinSCP nor PuTTY/psftp.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for confirmation. I double checked with my colleague, I'm able to use WinSCP. 
but tried above query seems not working.tried add-type -path ...\WinSCPnet.dll not working. tried loadfromfile not working. any idea?

Comment: *"not working"* does not work for us as a problem description. Edit your question with details on your attempts.

Comment: If the Linux box has samba running, you can transfer to the share using `xcopy \\linuxbox\smb_sharename\some\path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ansgar already commented, keys are used with SSH/SFTP. There's no support for SSH/SFTP in PowerShell nor in Windows 2008. If you need to use SSH/SFTP, you have to use 3rd party software/library.

And as already said above, you do not need *install privileges* to use WinSCP nor PuTTY/psftp.